# How to enable logical replication for an RDS PostgreSQL DB instance ? for DMS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

The scenario is that I want to CDC a table from a RDS postgreSQl to a RDS postgreSQL.

However my data migration task is not working and having this error

> Last Error Unable to use plugins to establish logical replication on
> source PostgreSQL instance. Follow all prerequisites for 'PostgreSQL
> as a source in DMS' from
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html
> Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2880] [1020490] Remaining 1 error messages
> are truncated. Check the task log to find details Stop Reason
> FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Following this document, I should

> Set the rds.logical_replication parameter in your DB CLUSTER parameter
> group to 1

I tried to run this in the database

> ALTER SYSTEM SET rds.logical_replication TO 1;

I got this error

> [42501] ERROR: must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can run an 'ALTER SYSTEM' statement on RDS databases. Create a parameter group with `rds.logical_replication` set to `1` and associate that parameter group to your DB instance.

Comment: On which database do we need to set rds.logical_replication . Is it source or the target database?